# How do I simulate SQL group by in tableau sheet?

Tags: sql, group-by, tableau-api

I am new to tableau. I have connect a table from the database to my tableau desktop as below:

[image: Patient Data]

And I would like to show the average cost and total patients based on the hospital.
In SQL query, I can easily use this query:

```
select 
  Hospital,
  count(*) as total_patients,
  avg(cost) average_cost
from table1
group by hospital
```

How do I simulate this in tableau?

Thanks before.

Answer (score 2):

To simulate your table, add the `Hospital` to the row shelf, `Measure Names` to column shelf, and `Measure Names` to filter shelf. There, filter only the measures to show (in this case, `Number of records` and `cost`).

Finally, add the field `Measure values` to the Text (Marks) shelf, and there, select the aggregation needed (click on cost >> Measure >> Average).

Answer (score 2):

Tableau generates what it calls Aggregate (aka group by) queries by default. You can change that from the Analysis menu, but seldom need to.

The fields that you want to group by are called Dimensions. The fields you are aggregating are called Measures. On the left side bar, in the data pane, fields have default role (dimension or measure), but you can override a field's role in any view.

Simply put Hospital on some shelf, say Rows, to get a row in the viz per hospital, and then your measures on another shelf, choosing your desired aggregation function. Then put SUM([Number of Records]) on Columns and AVG([Cost]) on Color. You can rearrange which fields are on which shelves and it doesn't change the query results, simply the presentation -- other than Filter and Tooltip shelves which are a bit different. You can also play with the Mark Type at the top of the Marks card to change the presentation.

Number of Records is simply a predefined calculated field that is equal to 1. So SUM([Number of Records]) is the same as COUNT(*). There is no field named * in Tableau, but you can use COUNT("*") if you prefer for the same effect.

As @Bob mentioned, you can also define Level of Detail (LOD) calculations using the curly brace and FIXED, INCLUDE, EXCLUDE syntax. These are complex calculations that let you define subqueries that get joined with the rest of your query to allow you to do calculations at different levels of detail. They are useful but add complexity and can degrade performance in large data sets, so reserve them for when you need them to get the correct result. Many (possibly most) visualizations can defined simply using dimensions and measures without writing an LOD calc.

I recommend avoiding the trap of writing everything as an LOD calc that some people seem to fall into when they have a lot of hand written SQL experience. FIXED LOD calc look like SQL, so they can be a familiar entity when starting out with Tableau.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your visual. If you plan to include hospital and patient, simply create two calculated fields-

Average cost-

```
AVG(cost)
```

Patient count-

```
count(patient_id)
```

Or, maybe you need to use a [Level of Detail Expression.](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.htm) FIXED level of detail expressions can have a finer level of detail than the view, a coarser level of detail, or the same level of detail. The need to aggregate the results of a FIXED level of detail depends on what dimensions are in the view.-

```
{ FIXED [hospital], [patient_id] : AVG(cost) } //Avg patient cost by hospital and patient id
{ FIXED [hospital] : COUNT(patient_id) } //# of non distinct patients by hospital
```